# Considering the Chaos Monkey in Designing and Architecting an Embedded Systems

Tags: c++, c, embedded, ada

I work on embedded systems with limited memory and throughput. Making a system more robust requires more memory, and time on the processor. I like the idea of the [Chaos Monkey](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/04/working-with-the-chaos-monkey.html) to figure out if your system is fault tolerant, however with limited resources I'm not sure how feasible it is to just keep adding code to it. Are there certain design considerations whether in the architecture or otherwise that would improve the fault handling capabilities, without necessarily adding "more code" to a system?

One way I have seen to help in preventing writing an if then statement in c (or c++) that assigns rather then compares a static value, recommends writing that on the left hand side of the comparison, this way if you try to assign your variable to say the number 5, things will complain and you're likely to find any issues right away.

Are there Architectural or Design decisions that can be made early on that prevent possible  redundancy/reliability issues in a similar way?

Comment: After reading the request to close, I would agree this might be better suited for the progammers.stackoverflow.com site, is it possible to move this or do I have to duplicate the question over there?

Comment: This is all over the place. You give an example of a testing technique, then you ask about design, then you give examples of coding practices, then you go back to asking about design. Pick your question!

Comment: I should note I once found a bug in someone's code where (using an ancient DEC compiler) he put a literal on the left side of a comparison, forgot the second `=`, and it thereafter replaced the value of that literal everywhere in his program with the contents of the variable he was trying to compare it to. It was a devil to track down.

Comment: Gilles While I agree it appears all over the place, the intention was to request ways to plan out a system architecturally, I used the "coding" example because well I just didn't have another example that was specific to architecture, but I liked the way that was thought out, the reason I was talking about testing, is I wanted to find ways to make the system more fault tolerant to things like code monkey, by architecting a better system, the high level here was architecting a system, so it's better at being fault tolerant from the start, I apologize I didn't make that clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes many other techniques can be used. You'd do well to purchase and read "Code Complete".

[Code Complete on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

Comment: I do have that book and it's a great read for anyone who hasn't read it.